# AngularJS + html5Mode and IE8/9 deep linking issue

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, deep-linking

I'm fighting with a well known issue with **AngularJS + HTML5 push state support  and legacy browsers**. In my particular case, I need a solution for IE8 and IE9.

I spent so many hours reading different posts, github issues, stackoverflow questions, with no luck for this workaround.

I've found a shim for that issue, and really worked but the last thing **I need to figure out** is to remove the hash state (#!) being added in these kind of browsers.

I mean, I need URL deep linking support with no hash.

For example,

`http://[siteurl]/customlink/support` and the only supported way for legacy browsers seems to be something like that:

`http://[siteurl]/#!/customlink/support`

Last, but not least, after some .htaccess rewrites, I can access to `http://[siteurl]/customlink` but, it seems that "two" levels doesn't work.

Does anybody had the same issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So you want IE to be okay with the links lacking #!, and not have angular automatically fall back to them? You're fighting against the tide here... I'm curious of your reasons for this? Why wouldn't you let angular manage this? In my testing, it copes well with the wrong link type going to the browser (falls back and forth automatically depending on browser, including deep links).

Comment: James, I don't think so. Reasons? Client requirements. We're porting an old site to a new responsive one and there are lot of SEO, Marketing Campaigns and other requirements to meet.
I figured out removing the #! programmatically only for IE and worked.
I really would like to keep angular handle this edge cases.

Comment: Makes, sense, good luck to you! I'm having trouble with ie9 deep linking myself in html5mode :)

Comment: Good luck! One thing, there are some issues with IE in case you don't add an ending slash. Every link, should end with / because, redirection don't work as expected.